# Cannot get code hinting to work with the official TypeScript plugin for Sublime Text 3

Tags: macos, typescript, angular, sublimetext3

I cannot get code hinting to work with the [official TypeScript plugin for Sublime Text 3](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/TypeScript) to work on Mac OSX 10.10.5 with Sublime 3.  I've installed it in the `packages` directory and I'm not seeing any code hinting.

I have a tsconfig.json file as it suggested, in the root of the app, the code is as follows.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "out": "out.js",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5"
    },
    "files": [
        "main.ts"
    ],
}
```

The following keep popping up tho, not sure what it wants me to do, I'm reading the Documentation, but it's not very clear.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try taking out that trailing comma on the second to last line. I don't think that's valid JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code:

```
"files": [
    "main.ts"
],
```

The trailing comma is invalid JSON: `,`.

## TIPs

Other IDEs like vscode and [alm](http://alm.tools/) will show you the error location as well.

Comment: Thank you, good catch. I'm still not getting code hinting tho :(

Comment: I played around with alm, and bingo, suddenly I had code hinting in sublime text, their json file seemed to work better :D Not sure why tho! :(